# How to add text over the image to get local storage key

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Text show over the image but text from local storage getitem(key)???? here is my code snippet to try my self.

```
<div id="map_div">

<img       src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Mercury_transit_1.jpg/220px-Mercury_transit_1.jpg"/>
</div>

$('<p>').appendTo('#map_div').
localStorage.getItem("draft[4006927]").css({position:'absolute',top:'100px,left:'70px'});
```

Comment: What is being returned by `localStorage.getItem("draft[4006927]") `

Comment: localstorage holds arbitrary data, not dom stuffs. you can't apply css to arbitrary data. why don't you tell us what you're tying to do..

Comment: i have retrive  some txt data

Answer (score 0):

Sort of guessing here but it looks like maybe you want the stuff from localstorage to show up in the (currently empty) paragraph you're appending.

```
$('<p>')
    .css({position:'absolute',top:'100px,left:'70px'})
    .append(localStorage.getItem("draft[4006927]"))
    .appendTo("#map_div");
```

Comment: i'd offer to help further, but "it's not working" is hardly helpful for debugging.